# Meteor routing filter not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i am trying to create an admin interface for my meteor project and for this i created a custom accounts register form which says

```
Accounts.createUser({
email: userEmail,
password: userPassword,
admin: true
})
```

and in my router.js code i have this

```
Router.route('/admin', {name: 'admin'})

var requireAdminLogin = function(){
if(!Meteor.user({admin: true})){
this.render('accessDenied')
}else{
this.next();
}
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireAdminLogin, {only: 'admin'})
```

the problem is even when i change my register code to say that the new user signing up is not admin, i can still get to my admin page. Can anyone help?  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package called [houston:admin](https://atmospherejs.com/houston/admin) did exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: I don't believe this is a link only answer. OP found a package which met his requirement and posted that as an answer. I've edited the answer to place less emphasis on the link.

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.user()` doesn't take any arguments. You probably want:

```
if (Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().admin) {
  // admin
} else {
  // access denied
}
```

I also suspect that passing the `admin` option to `Accounts.createUser` doesn't do anything. On the server, you could do `var userId = Accounts.createUser` followed by `Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {admin: true}});`.